# Python code speedup by storing commonly used list elements in local variables

Tags: performance, list, python-3.x, indexing

I have a Python code in which I have a list that some of its elements are referenced and used inside a loop that runs many times. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
for n in range(0, 1000000):
    a = my_list[n] * 2
    b = my_list[n] + my_list[n+1]
    c = my_list[n] * my_list[n+1]
    d = my_list[n] - my_list[n+1]
    my_function(a, b, c, d)
```

Is it faster to store `my_list[n]` and `my_list[n+1]` in two variables and then use them as:

```
for n in range(0, 1000000):
    my_list_n = my_list[n]
    my_list_np1 = my_list[n+1]        
    a = my_list_n  * 2
    b = my_list_n  + my_list_np1
    c = my_list_n  * my_list_np1
    d = my_list_n  - my_list_np1
    my_function(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? This should be pretty easy to test. I would guess that it might be faster, but probably not significantly so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try timing it:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def my_function(a, b, c, d):
    e=a*b*c*d

def f1():
    for n in range(0, 1000000):
        a = my_list[n] * 2
        b = my_list[n] + my_list[n+1]
        c = my_list[n] * my_list[n+1]
        d = my_list[n] - my_list[n+1]
        my_function(a, b, c, d)

def f2():    
    for n in range(0, 1000000):
        my_list_n = my_list[n]
        my_list_np1 = my_list[n+1]        
        a = my_list_n  * 2
        b = my_list_n  + my_list_np1
        c = my_list_n  * my_list_np1
        d = my_list_n  - my_list_np1
        my_function(a, b, c, d)    


def f3():
    for n in range(0, 1000000):       
        my_function(my_list[n] * 2,
                    my_list[n] + my_list[n+1],
                    my_list[n] * my_list[n+1],
                    my_list[n] - my_list[n+1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit       
    import sys
    print(sys.version)             
    my_list=range(1000001)
    n=2
    for f in (f1, f2, f3):
        res=timeit.timeit("{}()".format(f.__name__), setup="from __main__ import {}, my_list".format(f.__name__), number=n)
        print("{}: {:.3} secs".format(f.__name__, res))
```

Results for various python versions:

```
2.7.7 (default, Jun 14 2014, 23:12:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)]
f1: 2.27 secs
f2: 1.77 secs
f3: 2.07 secs

3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 13:10:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)]
f1: 4.14 secs
f2: 2.41 secs
f3: 4.16 secs

2.7.6 (32f35069a16d, Jun 06 2014, 20:12:47)
[PyPy 2.3.1 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)]
f1: 0.257 secs
f2: 0.241 secs
f3: 0.241 secs

3.2.5 (986752d005bb+, Jun 19 2014, 19:20:06)
[PyPy 2.3.1 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)]
f1: 0.267 secs
f2: 0.263 secs
f3: 0.269 secs
```

So in general, yes -- it is faster. How much depends on the version.

A quick observation is this is a good application for enumerate:

```
def f4():
    for n, e in enumerate(my_list[0:1000000]):  
        np1 = my_list[n+1]      
        my_function(e * 2,
                    e + np1,
                    e * np1,
                    e - np1)
```

Which is the fastest version of all.

Comment: And, whether that little bit of speedup even matters depends highly on what `my_function()` does. Shaving 1 second off an overall process that takes hours to run isn't a particularly stellar improvement...

Comment: @twalberg: Good point. Agreed. Readability matters as well as a tradeoff for what might be minor performance improvements.

Comment: thanks @dawg . I appreciate your help. Very interesting results. I see that the speed is almost an order of magnitude faster when you had `PyPy` instead of `GCC`. As I am a beginner in this can you please tell me what are those?

Comment: @dawg can I install it alongside my current Python 3.4.1 installation? Will it be a totally different program,, or it will cause issues and I need to keep one of them?

Comment: Yes -- it can be a different program and you can use the one that is best for your need script by script.

Comment: @TJ1: And it is not `PyPy` vs `GCC` It is regular cPython vs PyPy.